# Retrieve a photo from FB API GRAPH

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve a photo from fb doing this call:

> /id_photo?fields=picture

I take the field "**picture**" from the response and that give me an URL from where i can download the image.

The problem is that the image have a really poor quality and no matter if i change the parameters height and weight the result is the same.

**So how can i download a specific photo from facebook in a good quality?** (I have the photo ID)

Comment: `?fields=images` should give you all different photo sizes there are.

Comment: Awesome u right! Answer to my question if u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?fields=images` should give you all different photo sizes there are.

---

(Using `width` and `height` modifiers should also work, in theory - but depending on how close or not the sizes you request are to what's available, it might not always return the desired result. I have found it better to get all images sizes, and then pick the most appropriate one out of those.)